# How to keep the page state of previous page when going back from Navigation service?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a question about Prism Navigation related on Xamarin.Forms.

Let's say that I have 3 pages, the Navigation stack looks like `Navigation/ViewA/ViewB/ViewC`. When navigate from ViewA to ViewB, I have a List to pass as parameter, so basically in ViewB I will use `OnNavigatedTo` method to get the parameters and set the data to some bindable properties.

Then, from ViewB to ViewC, I also need to pass that same parameter, so this parameter is kind of going though the 3 views.

Then problem happened, when I go back from ViewC to ViewB, ViewB will still call OnNavigatedTo to get the parameters, but this time, since it's navigated from ViewC, so ViewC did not have the code to pass that parameter to ViewB.

Then, ViewB cannot get the parameter, then if by that time when to go to ViewC again, ViewC will not have the data that it needs to bind to the bindable properties.

So, my question is: Do I have to pass the same parameter again from ViewC to ViewB? If that's the resolution, then wouldn't it be a little bit stupid to do so? Any solution that we can keep the state of the previous page and when we go back from ViewC, everything is just there?

Thanks and look forward to the solution or any insights on this.

I only reproduce the issue and I know I can pass back the parameter again, but that will definitely not be an ideal solution for this problem.

Let's see. In ViewA:

```cs
private async void Navigate()
{
    var parameter = new NavigationParameter();
    parameter.Add("SomeData", list);
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewB", parameter);
}
```

In View B:

```cs
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameter paramters)
{
    // This code will be null when going back from ViewC
    var list = parameters["SomeData"] as List<string>();
    this.SomeBindableData = list;
}
```

ViewB used the same method as ViewA's navigate, and the problem occured when coming back from ViewC.

I would like an ideal solution for this problem. And please do help to check this by some guy from Prism team, I believe this is something needs to be handled.

Comment: Prism Provides NavigationMode using which you can detect whether it is new call / back call to the viewmodel....some thing like this inside OnNavigatedTo Method if (parameters.GetNavigationMode() == Prism.Navigation.NavigationMode.New)
            {
                //Parameter initialization
            }

Comment: Thanks for the comments Hamid, and yes, I am going to use that for my project. Actually I know that but I just got stuck on how to keep the state. It's in the navigation stack, so it remains there. So stupid of me this time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the View is in the Stack it won't be disposed or anything, so its state will be kept. Here you just have to know if your View is initialized or not:

In ViewB:

```
private bool _isInitialized;

public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameter paramters)
{
    if (_isInitialized)
        return;

    // This code will be null when going back from ViewC
    var list = parameters["SomeData"] as List<string>();
    this.SomeBindableData = list;
    _isInitialized = true;
}
```

Comment: I am gonna accept your answer but actually the comment from my original post is actually big help as well. I believe the better way is to combine what you guys mentioned, there is no need to use a `_isInitialized`, we can use the `parameters.GetNavigateionMode`, if that Mode is not Back, then just return. I implemented your solution and it did works, so thanks so much for the help so far. Just another thought for you as well.